# Zabbix : Invalid JSON

Tags: zabbix, json

I have a Powershell script returning a file like :

{
"data":[
{
"{#SHARENAME}":"Informatique",
"{#SHARENAME}":"Marketing"
}
]
}

I've set a discovery rule (zabbix agent) + an Item prototype (zabbix trapper) with the Key : sharename[{#SHARENAME}]

But the discovery rule says :

> Invalid discovery rule value: cannot parse as a valid JSON object:
> invalid object format, expected opening character '{' or '[' at: '/c
> zabbix_sender -c "C:\Program
> Files\Zabbix\Configurations\ZabbixAgentConf_x64_Custom.conf" -i
> C:\Temp\JSON.log sent: 0; skipped: 8; total: 8'

Why ?!

Answer (score 0):

Jsonlint reports an error stating "duplicated key" when trying to validate your file data.

Comment: I have nothing about that in logs. :(

Comment: Try https://jsonlint.com/ and validate the content of `C:\Temp\JSON.log`. Anyways the second error looks like the input does not contain a valid JSON structure. Eventually the `.log` file extention is wrong?

Comment: it is validated, I have already checked :(